# Using Coloumb Law to find the Electrical Field of a Cylinder along its axis

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

I'm stuck on this problem.
First, I found the electrical field of a disk, but now, I must find the electrical field of a cylinder and I don't know where to start.

The cylinder has a radius R and high L.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why not integrate the field of the disk along the height L?

Comment: Because i used theq surface charge density, and now i must use the volumetric density $\rho$.  Also, i need to differentiate the expression of the disk?

Comment: Can we assume that the cylinder is very long and that we are not considering the field near the ends of the cylinder?

Comment: No, we cant assume that, his length is L

Comment: I may have missed something, but what is the charge distribution? That seems essential to answering the question, unless you just need to construct the integral.

Answer (score 0):

I take volumetric charge density of the cylinder the constant $\rho$. At first we should calculate the electric field of a disk with surface charge density $\sigma$ and radius $R$ at height $z$ above its axis (you said you've find it but I just write it again):
$$
 \begin{split}
  dq = \sigma r dr d\varphi \to dE_z & = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{\sigma r dr d\varphi}{(r^2 + z^2)} \cos \theta,\  \cos \theta = \frac{z}{\sqrt{r^2 + z^2}}\\
  E_z & = \frac{\sigma z}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{R} \frac{r dr d\varphi}{(r^2 + z^2)^\tfrac32} \to E_z = \frac{\sigma}{2 \epsilon_0}(1-\frac{z}{\sqrt{R^2 + z^2}})
 \end{split}
$$
[image]

Using the element shown in the figure below we can relate $\rho$ and $\sigma$ this way:
$$
\pi R^2 \rho dz' = \pi R^2 \sigma \to \sigma = \rho dz'
$$
So we can find electric field at point $p$:
$$
dE_z = \frac{\rho dz'}{2 \epsilon_0} (1-\frac{z+z'}{\sqrt{R^2 + (z + z')^2}})
$$
$\quad$Now you should only integrate from $0$ to $l$:
$$
E_z = \frac{\rho}{2 \epsilon_0} \int_{0}^{l} (1-\frac{z+z'}{\sqrt{R^2 + (z + z')^2}}) dz'
$$[image]